# Tracking clicks on a specific button

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, onmousedown

I am new in unity. I have 4 buttons in my scene and each button has the same script.

In the script, I check the mouse click on the button and change its color. When you click on one of the buttons, each button changes color. It looks logical, but how can I change the color of the button on which the script is added?

UPD: I used this:

```
button.onClick.AddListener(delegate () { Click(); });
```

Thanks everyone for the help.

Comment: You would have to give each button an identifier (unless unity does this automatically) and then search for the button with that identifier and update it

Comment: Can you post your code and the inspector of one of the buttons?

Comment: How to track a click for a specific identifier?

I call this function in an Update:


`if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
{
   _buttonImage.color = Color.red;
}`

Answer (score 0):

You can add `private Button btn;` to your class and then `btn = GetComponent<Button>();` in Start()
Then you can access the button from the click method and change its color.